# How to call a method of a functional react component from another functional react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I'm trying to call the *showDrawer* methode of a functional component from another functional component.
What is the best practices to do so ? The other functional component is the wrapper.
Thanks!

```
  const TopSide = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const [key, setKey] = useState("1");

    const showDrawer = () => {
       console.log(key);
       setVisible(true);
    };

    const onClose = () => {
      setVisible(false);
  };

  [.....]

    }
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context? There are a few ways to tackle this, but the most obvious option is to move the state to the wrapper and just have `visible` be a prop. Not sure if that works for your use case, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan to change state of one component from another you should 'Raise' the state and the events that handels that.

```
    const showDrawer = () => {
       handelShowDrawer ()
    };

    const onClose = () => {
      setVisible(false);
  };

    }
Wrapper= ()=>{

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
   

    const handelShowDrawer = () => {
     
       setVisible(true);
    };

    const handelClose = () => {
      setVisible(false);
  };
 <TopSide handelShowDrawer={handelShowDrawer} onDrawerClose={handelClose} visible/>
  
}
```

Comment: That makes sence! Thank you